# Why does as.data.frame give error when converting a raster with factors as data and specifying xy=T?

Tags: r, r-raster

I would like to convert a raster layer into a dataframe and get the coordinates as well.

This works just fine, but doesn't give xy values:

```
as.data.frame(raster_layer)
```

> as.data.frame(x = naip_svm_cropped)
>
> ```
>                category
> 1   forest_broadleafdark
> 2   forest_broadleafdark
> 3   forest_broadleafdark
> 4              grassland
> 5              grassland
> 6              grassland
> ```

This throws an error:

```
as.data.frame(raster_layer, xy = T)
```

The error is:

> Error in match(round(v), rat$ID) :    error in evaluating the argument
>   'x' in selecting a method for function 'match': Error in v[, i] :
>   incorrect number of dimensions

I suspect the problem lies somewhere with the Raster Attribute Table, but am unsure how to proceed.  I suppose I could convert the factors to numeric and try going from there (`xy=T` works for non factor rasters), but I'd like to find out why adding `xy=T` gives this error.  So my question is really "Why does this happen, and how can I get it to work (return xy values with cell values)?"

The raster layer has factors as data (I'm not sure exactly how to call it, here is the str statement):

```
str(naip_svm_cropped@data)
Formal class '.SingleLayerData' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  ..@ offset    : num 0
  ..@ gain      : num 1
  ..@ inmemory  : logi FALSE
  ..@ fromdisk  : logi TRUE
  ..@ isfactor  : logi TRUE
  ..@ attributes:List of 1
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ ID      : num [1:5] 0 1 2 3 4
  .. .. ..$ category: Factor w/ 5 levels "forest_broadleafdark",..: 4 1 2 3 5
  ..@ haveminmax: logi TRUE
  ..@ min       : num 0
  ..@ max       : num 4
  ..@ band      : int 1
  ..@ unit      : chr ""
  ..@ names     : chr "madison_classcombine"
```

The behavior on a dataframe with a structure like this:

```
str(mad_veg_cropped@data)
Formal class '.SingleLayerData' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
 ..@ values    : logi(0) 
 ..@ offset    : num 0
  ..@ gain      : num 1
  ..@ inmemory  : logi FALSE
  ..@ fromdisk  : logi TRUE
  ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
  ..@ attributes: list()
  ..@ haveminmax: logi TRUE
  ..@ min       : num -0.719
  ..@ max       : num 1.04
  ..@ band      : int 1
  ..@ unit      : chr ""
  ..@ names     : chr "PercentVeg"

head(as.data.frame(mad_veg_cropped, xy = T))
       x       y   PercentVeg
1 291855.5 4775116  0.7182595
2 291856.5 4775116  0.7402779
3 291857.5 4775116  0.7601378
4 291858.5 4775116  0.7702084
5 291859.5 4775116  0.7774438
6 291860.5 4775116  0.7574666
```

I'd like to be able to get a column of "category", "x", and "y".

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
>   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
>   other attached packages:
>   [1] raster_2.3-24 sp_1.0-17

```
dput(naip_svm_cropped)
    new("RasterLayer"
        , file = new(".RasterFile"
        , name = "/private/var/folders/yj/vjkj1yyx1n510rf_rggqdb640000gr/T/R_raster_tedward/2015-06-04_122215_4840_06850.grd"
        , datanotation = "INT2S"
        , byteorder = structure("little", .Names = "value")
        , nodatavalue = -32768
        , NAchanged = FALSE
        , nbands = 1L
        , bandorder = structure("BIL", .Names = "value")
        , offset = 0L
        , toptobottom = TRUE
        , blockrows = 0L
        , blockcols = 0L
        , driver = "raster"
        , open = FALSE
    )
        , data = new(".SingleLayerData"
        , values = logical(0)
        , offset = 0
        , gain = 1
        , inmemory = FALSE
        , fromdisk = TRUE
        , isfactor = TRUE
        , attributes = list(structure(list(ID = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), category = structure(c(4L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("forest_broadleafdark", "grassland", 
    "shadow1_tree", "Unclassified", "urban_buildings"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
    "category"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"))
        , haveminmax = TRUE
        , min = 0
        , max = 4
        , band = 1L
        , unit = ""
        , names = "madison_classcombine"
    )
        , legend = new(".RasterLegend"
        , type = character(0)
        , values = logical(0)
        , color = logical(0)
        , names = logical(0)
        , colortable = c("#000000", "#008B00", "#FF0000", "#FFFF00", "#FF00FF")
    )
        , title = character(0)
        , extent = new("Extent"
        , xmin = 291855
        , xmax = 311023
        , ymin = 4768423
        , ymax = 4775116
    )
        , rotated = FALSE
        , rotation = new(".Rotation"
        , geotrans = numeric(0)
        , transfun = function () 
    NULL
    )
        , ncols = 19168L
        , nrows = 6693L
        , crs = new("CRS"
        , projargs = "+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
    )
        , history = list()
        , z = list()
    )
```

Comment: You are asking for conversion of a discrete class to a numeric class. Seems reasonable to throw an error. Why not post `dput(naip_svm_cropped)` if you want a tested workaround.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if I'm being clear or if I don't understand what you mean.  I'll try to make the question more specific, but I'm not trying to change the factors to numeric.  I'm trying to get xy values in addition to the factor level assigned to each pixel.

Comment: I think I understand. I suggested you post `dput()` from the object so we actually have some data to work with.

Comment: ah, gotcha.  I've never done that before, but will post it.  Let me know how to modify if needed (it will be lengthy)

Comment: Thanks. I did try to reconstruct a raster from that dput-output but am getting an error that doesn't make sense to me. If I had a bunch of free time (more) I would search in the SIG-geo archives,.

Comment: OK, thanks for your efforts, I'll try to find a work around.

Comment: dput is often not very useful for Raster objects as they often depend on data in a file that you won't have access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'raster' expects that the first column of the raster attribute table is an integer variable named 'ID'. How did you get this layer? Perhaps this is a bug that needs to be fixed, or perhaps you made a mistake when you created it.

Either way, here is a work around that should work:

```
xy <- xyFromCell(raster_layer, 1:ncell(raster_layer))
v <- as.data.frame(raster_layer) 
xyv <- data.frame(xy, v)
```

Here is a self-contained example

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] = 1
r[51:100] = 2
r[3:6, 1:5] = 3
r <- ratify(r)

rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$landcover <- c('Pine', 'Oak', 'Meadow')
rat$code <- c(12,25,30)
levels(r) <- rat

xy <- xyFromCell(r, 1:ncell(r))
v <- as.data.frame(r) 
xyv <- data.frame(xy, v)

head(xyv)
#     x  y landcover code
#1 -162 81      Pine   12
#2 -126 81      Pine   12
#3  -90 81      Pine   12
```

although in this example, you can also do:

```
vv <- as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it solves my problem.  Seems like the error was very particular to my raster object (which may be related to how it was created, reading in a tiff)